# Применения javascript паттерна модуль

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, вёрстка, шаблоны-проектирования

Прочел [Паттерн Модуль](https://metanit.com/web/javascript/3.9.php) и [Разбор паттерна модуль в javascript](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/419997/)

В каких реальных задачах (приведите текст условий) может использоваться паттерн модуль?

P.S. (вообще это похоже на обычное ооп, в котором данные являются приватными, а доступ к ним осуществляются в публичных методах и свойствах, при этом получается, что объявление общедоступных методов вместе с объявлением объекта образуют замыкание относительно приватных данных).